# ASP.NET and Jquery PageMethods Failing after publish

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7.5, pagemethods

I'm using Jquery and ASP.NET with ajax calling PageMethods. In the dev evironment (VS2010) everything works/tests great. I published it for the first time to show off the project and couldn't get it working with the published files on IIS 7.5...all PageMethods calls failed.

-Does anybody know what may be causing the issue? Missing something from web.config? A reference missing? IIS setting? Any thoughts would be a big help.

Thanks.

Comment: Relative Urls in your Ajax calls? Utilize F12 in Firefox, IE, or Chrome and watch your Console to see any 500 errors (or something).

Comment: got it working by running this '%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was an IIS/ASP.NET issue.

Got it working on localhost IIS by running:
`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

I'll update if there are any issues applying this to production web server.

Comment: The production server was a different issue. Of course the ASP was registered but the PageMethods still didn't work. In IIS we had to set the app pool to allow 32bit bit application.

Everything is working now.